# how to fill a scripted field value by condition in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

i am using Kibana 4 and my document contains two integer fields called: 'x' & 'y'. i would like to create a scripted field in Kibana returning the division value of 'x' by 'y' if 'y'<> 0. else: return the value of 'x'.

i have tried to add this script to a new screnter code hereipted field: 

    `doc['x'].value  > 0 ? doc['x'].value/doc['y'].value : doc['x'].value;`

but got a parsing error when trying to visualize it:

> Error: Request to Elasticsearch failed: 
>   {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], 
>   all shards failed; shardFailures

how can i create a scripted field with condition in Kibana, step by step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is not a parsing error, `shardFailures` just means that the underlying Elasticsearch is not ready yet. When starting Kibana/Elasticsearch, make sure your ES cluster is ready before diving into Kibana, i.e. run `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/health` and in the response, you should see something similar to this:

```
{
    cluster_name: your_cluster_name
    status: yellow           <----- this must be either yellow or green
    timed_out: false
    number_of_nodes: 2
    number_of_data_nodes: 2
    active_primary_shards: 227
    active_shards: 454
    relocating_shards: 0     <----- this must be 0
    initializing_shards: 0   <----- this must be 0
    unassigned_shards: 25
}
```

As for your script, it is written correctly, however the condition you mentioned is not correct since you wanted `y <> 0` and not `x > 0`, so it should be

```
 doc['y'].value != 0 ? doc['x'].value / doc['y'].value : doc['x'].value
```

Please give it a try